# Is it possible to search using comma(,) in a single search field?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, openerp-6

In openerp v6, I have a function field named zone

```
'zone' : fields.function(_get_zone, string="Zone", type='char', fnct_search=_zone_search),
```

I haven't create the _zone_search yet, anyone know how to make that function search by multiple input using comma(,) in just that one 'zone' field?

Example
Zone = 12, 14, 15

Comment: Really, the best thing to do is not do that in the first place. Comma-separated lists in DB columns are bad design. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/398670, http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55871/7788, http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/17808/7788

Comment: I am not saying that I save that zone field in DB, but I want to know it is possible to search multiple data (not using comma) in DB by using just only one filed

Comment: In that case I don't understand the question.

Comment: Please add your question with example code. Like what your tried so far ? You made two function. 1. *_zone_search* and 2. *_get_zone*. And also insert any trace-back occurs.